# Should we add review queues to the API?

Tags: feature-request, api, review

Review queues are unsupported on the Stack Exchange API, and it could be useful to write an app that would review.  Should we add it to the API?

Comment: I'm not against the idea per sé, but I do think it might lead to more (literal) robo-reviewers. They are a problem already right now...

Comment: @Glorfindel If I wanted to be a robo-reviewer, I think I could easily do it at this point without the API by automatically clicking the right buttons, so I don't think adding an API option would change much.  If anything it would make it more secure, because the API could be programmed to not reveal when something's an audit.

Answer (score 1):

You would need to demonstrate that your reviewing app contained sufficiently advanced AI to be able to correctly perform the review.

Reviewing takes time and effort and involves checking many aspects of the post.  This would be a major AI project.

The risk of robo-reviewing or just plain making wrong decisions is too great.  Consequently, the risk of degrading the quality of the site(s) is too great.

I can see that a reviewing app could be built in stages, example first attempt: just look for NAA and skip everything else.  Then build upon the app by adding other tasks.  However, you would still need to demonstrate the effectiveness of the app before the powers that be would want to let it loose on the real community.

Comment: I'm not thinking about making an app that would robo-review, I want to make a desktop app that would allow humans to manually review without visiting the web interface.

Comment: @Anonymous just curious: what's wrong with the web interface? And wouldn't it be (much) easier to change the interface through a userscript?

Comment: @Glorfindel I'm thinking of making a desktop app for Stack Exchange, which would have a different UI and more features (mostly to learn about the API, and to add a lot of ideas I had that would clash with the design of the site) and I think it would be useful to add review capabilities, so you wouldn't have to go to a different interface every time you wanted to review.